# Does every Lie algebra have commutator as its Lie bracket up to isomorphism?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, lie-derivative

We know that not every Lie algebra has commutator $XY-YX$ as its Lie bracket. For example, $R^3$ with vector cross product. However, every Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X(Y)=XY-YX$ of a Lie group is a commutator (by differentiating push-forward of a vector field by a flow of another vector field at $0$). Therefore by Lie group-Lie algebra correspondence, I believe every Lie algebra is $isomorphic$ to some Lie algebra with commutator Lie bracket. In above example, $(R^3, \times) \cong (\mathfrak{so_3}, [,])$ as Lie algebras, where the latter has commutator Lie bracket.

My attempt is as follows. Given $\mathfrak{g}$ a Lie algebra, we are done by finding a Lie group which it is tangential to. The idea is to consider the adjoint representation $ad: \mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{gl(g)}$ with kernel $Z(\mathfrak{g})$. So we consider $exp(\mathfrak{g}/Z(\mathfrak{g})) \ltimes R^k$ where $k=dim\ Z(\mathfrak{g})$. This $exp(\mathfrak{g}/Z(\mathfrak{g}))$ corresponds to a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl(g)}$ so has commutator as Lie bracket. To make the dimension right we just append $R^k$ to compensate the dimension of the kernel of $ad$.

I am new to Lie theory so I am not sure if my intuition on vector field composition or exponential maps are correct. I could not find a proof of this anywhere.

Any suggestions and corrections are very much appreciated.

Comment: By *Ado's (and Iwasawa's) theorem*, every finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a field is isomorphic to a Lie algebra of matrices with Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$. This is enough for a positive answer to your question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you a lot! Problem solved!

Comment: @DietrichBurde What you wrote looks more like an answer than a comment to me.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem) for this important theorem. I wrote a wikipedia entry about [Ado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Dmitrievich_Ado), if you are interested :)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can write an answer, but it would be just the statement of Ado's theorem. The moderators were critical lately for such  "trivial" answers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I still think that it is an answer. Let us see [what the moderators think about it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59025316#59025316).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Apart from Ado's theorem, do you have any thoughts about my attempt? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I have. Basically you want to prove Ado's theorem, is this correct?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh I see. I will go to check the proofs. Thank you!

Comment: If one wants to avoid Ado's Theorem (and learn about something good), one can alternatively embed a Lie algebra into its *universal enveloping algebra*. There, the Lie bracket identifies with a commutator of an associative algebra by definition. By the way, this forces upon us to make the question a bit more precise: Is our Lie algebra itself supposed to be closed under the associative product in the commutator? I think neither construction so far achieves that.

Comment: The first sentence sounds unclear. Are you addressing the question which Lie algebras have a bracket of the for $XY-YX$ for some bilinear product $(X,Y)\mapsto XY$? What do you want to assume on the product? associative? unital? without assumption, one can always choose $XY=\frac12[X,Ÿ]$.